# How do I reset a select list in AngularJS and track by?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-track-by

I have a select list.

```
<select id="search.month" 
  ng-model="search.month" 
  class="form-control" 
  ng-options="item as item.name for item in months track by item.id">
 </select>
```

I reset the list

```
$scope.reset = function () {
  $scope.search = {reportType: 0, month: 0, year: 0 };
};
```

Nothing happens. 
AngularJS 1.5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14892) in 1.4 + of AngularJs. Up to at least 1.5.8 in my experience.

Manually reset the list with jQuery. Ignores angularJS.

```
$scope.reset = function () {
  $scope.search = {reportType: 0, month: 0, year: 0 };
  // Manually reset.
  // https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14892
  $('#search\\.month').find('> option').each(function() {
     $(this).removeAttr('selected');
  });

  $('#search\\.year').find('> option').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('selected');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function :

```
$scope.resetDropDown = function() {
 $scope.temp = $scope.search.month; // Before reset select box, get selected value
    $scope.search.month = "";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. $scope.temp starts off as 0 and I already set $scope.search.month to 0 in   $scope.search = {reportType: 0, month: 0, year: 0 };